# convert month-day string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column for month-day in the format of '1-29' ( no data for year). I want to convert it from a string to datetime.

I have produced a sample dataframe as follows;

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[78,18,94,55,68,57,78,8],
                   'monthday':['1-29','1-28','1-27','1-19','1-28','1-19','1-29','1-28']})
```

I have tried
`df['month_day']= [datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%d') for x in df.monthday]`

but the output inserts a year and I end up with 1900-01-29.

Also, with my full dataframe I end up with the error 'ValueError: day is out of range for month'.

Comment: What value do you want to use for the year? A datetime object includes a year

Comment: I was hoping to leave the year out, since all values in the dataframe would belong to the same year

Comment: A python datetime object has a year, month, day, and time, so you'll have to provide values for those or use the defaults (1900 for year and 00:00:00 for time in this case). If you're getting the 'day is out of range' error, it's probably because you have the date 2-29 in there somewhere, and 1900 is not a leap year.